# How keep the only portions of the word/string withing two delimiter?

Tags: r, string, text, split

```
//@john:awesome play @user2:great....//@user3:wow%oke"kakaa"
@user5:aha@user3:hello
@user6:helloow @user7:database @user1:ok
```

The result i want is the users, i.e the word/string between "@" and ":", i have tried to split

```
text_1 = strsplit(as.character(df$text), '(?<=[^@])(?=@)', perl=TRUE)
```

but the result is not what i wish
I want the result to be like the following

```
john user2 user3
user5 user3
user6 user7 user1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `string` is your string, you can try:

```
  regmatches(gregexpr("(?<=@)[^:]+",string,perl=TRUE),x=string)[[1]]
  #[1] "john"  "user2" "user3" "user5" "user3" "user6" "user7" "user1"
```